# Defining of a path for php for a sub domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created a sub domain eg , for main domain abc.com , dfg.abc.com.

The files are stored in the folder  public_html/xyz/dfg.

The file hij.php is in the the folder public_html/xyz/dfg .

How do i define include_once($path_to_root . "/hij.php");?

When i run the code get an error ;

> include_once(./hij.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file: /home/.../public_html/xyz/dfg/includes/session.inc at line nnn.

Any help given will be highly appiciated.

Regards

Azhar

Comment: Where are you including the hij.php file, I mean where is the location of the file where that file is included?

Answer (score 0):

```
$root_directory_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
$pathName = $root_directory_path."/xyz/dfg/hij.php";
include_once($pathName);
```

Let me know if that solved the issue :)

Comment: include_once(/home/kensofts/public_html/SolutionsDemo/kenErp/SolutionsDemo/kenErp/Kenerp.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file: /home/kensofts/public_html/SolutionsDemo/kenErp/includes/session.inc at line 366

Comment: Ok so from that error, you know that the code is looking for Kenerp.php in the right location. Have you double checked the name or file extension of Kenerp.php? maybe you have it as Kenerp.html?

Comment: Thank you Weberg , it has worked How do rate the solution?

Comment: @Kensoftwares there is an area on the left part my answer where you click and a green checkmark appears. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You may try;

```
include_once(../hij.php)
```

instead of one `.`, use two `..`